# Inserting GIF file in LyX

Tags: graphics, lyx, conversion, gif

In short, I'm having trouble inserting gif files into LyX; when I try to view the PDF I get the message:

„No information for converting gif format files to png. Define a converter in the preferences.“

Some guides said that I should have ImageMagick and Ghostscript installed, but that didn't solve the problem.

If someone could help me do it on the fly without having to convert gif manually to something that LyX can process, that would be great—even better if no LaTeX code is involved.

Comment: assuming you have imagemagic then simply convert the gif to png and include the png.

Comment: I am aware that I can do it manually, converting and spliting GIF into PNG sequence with Imagemagick and then using something like the „animate package“, but it isn't ideal.

Comment: As far as I am aware you can't include an animated gif in pdf  (that is it is a restriction of the pdf format not of latex/lyx) so _something_ has to do that in order to generate pdf in the end. (you should probably say that you want animated gifs as converting a normal single frame gif to a png on the fly while including into latex would be a somewhat simpler question, although personally I'd still convert to png first)

Comment: I actually did it before with Texstudio; It was also possible to include videos using Media9 package, although only Adobe reader and sometimes Foxit reader used to show it and play it. I should include that I'm on Windows.

Comment: Your actual problem isn't quite clear. Do you want animated or stationary (single image) Gifs be made ready for insertion into PDF? Note that direct inclusion of Gif in either form is not supported by the PDF format. Or do you want to configure your TeX editor to automate the conversion process for Gifs which was explained elsewhere?

Comment: @FritjofLarsson I suggest to post a minimal example .tex file and minimal example .gif file that you want to include in your .tex file. After we figure out the correct LaTeX code then we can start thinking of the corresponding LyX procedures. By the way, welcome to tex.se!